# How to rename a variable in a batch script and keep the data

Tags: batch-file

I’m trying to parse some information from an XML file with a batch script and I have not been able to figure out how to rename the variable and keep the data intact. The output file is HTML which is what the device that is reading the data needs.

The batch file creates the HTML file just fine. The device is looking for Temperature: 75 and that is what it looks like in the file however if you check the file with a HTML editor the search name is included in the variable and the device can't use the data.

This is what I have been working on;

```
@echo off

start /b /WAIT %~dp0bitsadmin.exe /transfer "currentstats" 
https://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KMGM.xml %~dp0Weather.xml

for %%a in (%~dp0Weather.xml) do (
for /f "tokens=* " %%b in ( ' type "%%a" ^|findstr /i "temp_f" ' ) do set tem1="%%b"
for /f "tokens=* " %%b in ( ' type "%%a" ^|findstr /i "relative_humidity" ' ) do set 
hum1="%%b"
)

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%P in ("<HTML>") do ( @echo %%P > %~dp0Weather.html)
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%P in (%tem1%) do ( @echo Temperature: %%P >> %~dp0Weather.html)
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%P in ("<BR />") do ( @echo %%P >> %~dp0Weather.html)
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%P in (%hum1%) do ( @echo Humidity: %%P >> %~dp0Weather.html)
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%P in ("</HTML>") do ( @echo %%P >> %~dp0Weather.html)
```

Data sample (from comments) Line breaks assumed.

```
<HTML> Temperature: <temp_f>75.0</temp_f> <BR />
Humidity: <relative_humidity>62</relative_humidity>
</HTML>
```

I Can’t figure how to remove the Left & Right pointing single angle quotation marks and what is between them so I end up with this.

```
<HTML> Temperature: 75.0 <BR />
Humidity: 62
</HTML>
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: OP: Use the `edit` button to include the data. As you see, putting it in a comment makes it illegible. Please check my reformat. line breaks are important in batch, so make appropriate edits if necessary. You do not have any carets as posted. A caret is `^`. Perhaps you mean close-tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing this using PowerShell instead. Using PowerShell you should be able to grab the data directly instead of downloading and reading an XML file. It also affords you the opportunity to output directly to HTML.

Example:

**WeatherData.ps1**

```
$weather_url = "https://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KMGM.xml"
$request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($weather_url)
$request.UserAgent = "MyApplication/v1.0 (http://foo.bar.baz; foo@bar.baz)"
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument    
$doc.Load($response.GetResponseStream())
$doc.current_observation | ConvertTo-HTML -As List @{Label = 'Temperature'; Expression = {[Int]$_.temp_f}}, @{Label = 'Humidity'; Expression = {$_.relative_humidity}} | Out-File ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path.DirectoryName + 'weather.html')
```

To run that from a batch file, use this, *(obviously changing `%UserProfile%\Desktop\` as needed)*:

**WeatherTest.cmd**

```bash
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "%UserProfile%\Desktop\WeatherData.ps1"
```

The output file `weather.html` should be located in the cmd.exe instance's current directory.

**Note:** If you want the decimal temperature, as opposed to the whole integer, as I used above, change `[Int]$_.temp_f` to just `$_.temp_f`.

---

If I chose to do this using only a batch file, then I'd use the built-in `curl.exe` utility, instead of `bitsadmin.exe`:

**WeatherData.cmd**

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "_=" & For /F "Tokens=3 Delims=<>" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe
 "https://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KMGM.xml" -H "Accept: Application/XML"
 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IL "<temp_f> <relative_humidity>"
 ') Do @(If Not Defined _ (Set /P "=<HTML>Temperature: %%G<BR />" 0<NUL
    Set "_=.") Else Set /P "=Humidity: %%G</HTML>" 0<NUL & Echo(
) 1>>"%~dp0weather.html"
```

---

Here's a modification which is of no purpose to any future user, and only included for the OP:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "_=" & For /F "Tokens=3 Delims=<>" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe
 "https://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KMGM.xml" -H "Accept: Application/XML"
 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IL "<temp_f> <relative_humidity>"
 ') Do @(If Not Defined _ (Set /P "=<HTML>Temperature: %%G<BR />" 0<NUL
    Set "_=.") Else Echo(&Echo Humidity: %%G&Echo ^</HTML^>
) 1>>"%~dp0weather.html"
```

Comment: Outstanding! This does pull the numeric values I'm looking for but the html file has everything in one line. How can this be modified to output the data on seperate lines?

Comment: That is valid HTML, there is no difference to that and what you posted, other than it makes more sense than the abomination you posted. The only other acceptable option would have been to include a new line character instead of the space character at line 1 position 7. Open the html file, you'll clearly see that it is displayed exactly as it should be.

Comment: Ouch! "abomination"? I am trying my best to ask for help with something I am working on. The software on the piece of equipment I am trying to get working is looking for an html file with the variable information on seperate lines. Opening the file with a browser shows things on seperate lines but using an html editor the weather.html file has everything on one line. How can we configure the code to place html on one line, Temperature: 60 on one line Humidity: 35 on one line and the html close on the last line?  Thanks for any help or direction.

Comment: This is an old Time and Temp character generator unit here at the TV station. We are trying to repurpose for another project. It used to go out and get the data it needed but that service is no longer available. We are trying to read the data at NOAA and save it to an html file like it wants.
The file it is looking for looks more like a web page with everything on separate lines. The code above creates one line and the CG doesn’t read it. I can edit the file and place everything on separate lines and the CG reads it properly.
Sorry to be such a pain, I’m not a code writer.

Comment: I have added a version to the bottom of my answer, only for you @Rick1975. I will not be making any further changes from this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74092241.txt"
SET "omit="^<temp_f^>" "^</temp_f^>" "^<relative_humidity^>" "^</relative_humidity^>""

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%e"
 FOR %%y IN (%omit%) DO SET "line=!line:%%~y=!"
 echo !line!
)
GOTO :EOF
```

I believe the key is to "escape" (turn off the special meaning) of <kbd>></kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd><</kbd> with a caret <kbd>^</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler to define what data you want to keep, rather than what data you want to remove! Just do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define keep values:
set "HTML=<HTML>"
set "BR /=<BR />"
set "/HTML=</HTML>"

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (Weather.xml) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "line=!line:<=%%!"
   call set "line=!line:>=%%!"
   echo !line!
)) > Weather.html
```

Change any `<name>` by `%name%` and evaluate the result line. All `%varNames%` that don't exists will be deleted...